# Generalisation of a term (bSc)

Tags: calculus

Someone tell me how that [image]underlined term is generalised.

---

I mean
I know how solve such questions but i didn't get that underlined.

---

I got my ans. About generalization but still i'm confused about the -1
How is it generalised?

Comment: Just try to predict $y_8(0) $, $y_{10}(0)$ as the book have done you will get the answer.

Comment: Yeah it is making a pattern like

Comment: Product of square of n +ve even numbers

Comment: Correct! now try to generalize the pattern and try to verify it for $y_{12}(0)$ and calculate $y_{12}(0)$ manually.

Comment: But what about the -ve 1

Comment: I didn't get about -1

Comment: The -1 gets +1 whenever it squared so we adjust it like $(-1)^{2n}=1$ suitably according to the problem

Comment: Try to write the entire problem in the problem section of Math Stack page.